# image thumbnail in RSS Feed

Tags: rss, thumbnails

I dont have much coding knowledge. getting prob with RSS feed. I copy n pasted from somewhere this code. getting title and date.. its fine, but client needs now image thumbnail too. How to put image thumbnail. plz help me..

check below code...

```
<li> <p> <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y'); ?> </p>
     <a target="_blank" href='<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>'
     title='<?php echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?>'> 
    <strong> <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?> </strong></a>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the native RSS feeds then the post thumbnail can be added by a filter hook:

```
function insertThumbnailRSS($content) {
    global $post;
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title(), 'style' => 'float:right;' ) ) . '' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'insertThumbnailRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'insertThumbnailRSS');
```

But if you are creating a custom feed then you can add the image using the_post_thumbnail eg:

```
<li>
    <p><?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y'); ?></p>
        <a target="_blank" href='<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>'title='<?php echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?>'> 
        <strong> <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?> </strong></a>
        <?php // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } 
        ?>
}</li>
```